# Saving data with object-based data source in winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a C# winforms application which needs to read in data from multiple files and allow the user to view/edit the data. There will be a large amount of data, so the user needs to be able to save their changes, close the program, and resume their work later.

I am struggling with the best approach for retaining this data after the user exits the program. I've followed a [tutorial for data binding to objects](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial), but in this tutorial the data is hardcoded into the Form_Load event and the changes are lost when you exit the program. The author alludes to preferring to use an object-based data source instead of a database for data binding, but doesn't describe on how/if he saves data after the user exits.

Is there a way to store the data in the object-based data source between sessions, without setting up a local database or manually writing to some type of file? Or must I set up a local database in order to save data?

Comment: You can use serialization to serialize objects to files.

Comment: Do you mean you have a class object model, a class structure of sort, which contains user data, that you need to save to disc? If so, you just need a form of serialization. JSON and XML are the most common. You can serialize and deserialize complex structures to simple text files. See the many questions related to JSON, [Json.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) (NewtonSoft Json) or [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json) (.Net Core 3.0+)

Comment: @Jimi yes this sounds like what I need. I assume I would serialize the BindingSource object (rather than the underlying object)?

Comment: No, the object (List of objects/Dictionary/whatever) used as the DataSource of the BindingSource. This depends on your data structure. You may need to serialize/deserialize more than one structure, in multiple files. You *could* serialize the BidingSource surce inner list (the BindingListSource generated when the DataSource is set), but I don't suggest to do it: you need your original data structure back, then resume the bindings when all your data *chunks* are reloaded in their original class *containers*.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi this was what I needed to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As users Jimi and bhmahler mentioned in the comments, the concept I was looking for was Object Serialization.

I created the following method to save my data:

```
private void Serialize()
{
    Stream s = File.Open("data.txt", FileMode.Open); 
    BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
    List<Airplane> data = new List<Airplane>();
    foreach (var a in bsAirplanes) //bsAirplanes is the bindingsource object
    {
        data.Add((Airplane)a);
    }
    b.Serialize(s, data);
    s.Close();
}
```

And this method to load saved data:

```
private void Deserialize()
{
    Stream s = File.OpenRead("data.txt");
    BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
    List<Airplane> data = (List<Airplane>) b.Deserialize(s);
    foreach(Airplane a in data)
    {
        bsAirplanes.Add(a);
    }
    s.Close();
}
```

I also had to mark the Airplane class with the `[Serializable()]` attribute.